# .append inside .html is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display multiple data using .append using for loop.
I need all data to be replaced by second click to some other data by .html function.

This is my code for more explanation.

```
$(".content").html(function(){
  for(var l=1; l<4 ; l++)
    $(".content").append("Event-"+l+"<br>"+player.activity[l].desc+"<br>");
 }
```

suppose I have activity json like below:

```
player : [{
"name": "Johny", 
"activity" :  [
    {"id:1","desc" : "abc"},
    {"id:2","desc" : "abc"},
    {"id:3","desc" : "abc"}
 ]
},{
"name": "Mony", 
"activity" :  [
    {"id:1","desc" : "abc"},
    {"id:2","desc" : "abc"},
    {"id:3","desc" : "abc"}
]
}]
```

So basically I want to replace my Johny's activity to mony's.

I also tried swapping the methods such as .html inside .append which is working fine but .appnd inside .html is not working. It is appending the Mony's data to johny's data.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you leave just `for` outside `.html`s function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Functions [is not allowed](https://api.jquery.com/html/) in the `.html` method. Only strings.</strike>

Your `for` should do exactly what you want. Do not place inside `.html`'s function:

```
for(var l=1; l<4 ; l++)
  $(".content").append("Event-"+l+"<br>"+player.activity[l].desc+"<br>");
}
```

If you want to replace the content then just call `.html` with empty string before `for`:

```
$(".content").html("");
for(var l=1; l<4 ; l++)
  $(".content").append("Event-"+l+"<br>"+player.activity[l].desc+"<br>");
}
```

---

UPDATE

It's better to build a string and change DOM only once. This will reduce DOM access.

```
var html = "";
for(var l=1; l<4 ; l++)
  html += "Event-"+l+"<br>"+player.activity[l].desc+"<br>";
}
$(".content").html(html);
```

---

UPDATE #2

Functions allowed but `return` should be used:

```
$(".content").html(function(){
  var html = "";
  for(var l=1; l<4 ; l++)
    html += "Event-"+l+"<br>"+player.activity[l].desc+"<br>";
  }
  return html;
});
```

Comment: Sorry yes, allowed. I updated. `return` should be used

Comment: @phts thnx for answer. I have used empty .html method.

Answer (score 1):

This code is very much buggy.

1) .html() should have parameter as string not a function.

2)  Player is array player.activity[l] won't work.

If you want to see all description : following is the solution

```
for(var i=0; i<player.length ; i++){
     for(var j=0; j<player[i].length ; j++){

        $(".content").append("Event-"+j+"<br>"+player[i].activity[j].desc+"<br>");
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thnx for your suggestion. But I wanted to replace one block of information with other which I could achieved by putting before .html(" ") before for loop

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) says:

> As of jQuery 1.4, the `.html()` method allows the HTML content to be set by passing in a function

So, yes, you may use a function inside `.html()`. The function must return a string, which will be the content of the element.

```
$(".content").html(function(){
    var content = "";
    for (var l = 1; l < 4 ; l++) {
        content += "Event-" + l + "<br>" + player.activity[l].desc + "<br>";
    }
    return content;
 });
```

Comment: but this is not passing a function. Actually passing a string only. In the function() you are returning a string. The .html() method actually called with a string.

Comment: No, we are not calling the function, just passing it. Please note there is no function call operator inside the `.html()` call

Comment: But you cannot deny that .html() has parameter string. we can write the code in many ways. But finally it must be String

Comment: Well, the jQuery function will call our function inside, and that call will yield a string of course.